# Trouble loading the IMAP extension (with OSX El Capitan)

Tags: php, imap, osx-elcapitan

I need to use the IMAP extension but apparently I'm having some problems. I've reinstalled PHP7 using first "`brew unlink php70`", then "`brew install php70 --with-imap`". I've uncommented the "`extension=php_imap.dll`" in my php.ini, but I still get this error :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_imap.dll'
>   - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_imap.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

basically, whenever I try to do anything.

I've tried navigating the directories and can't find the "*extensions*" directory in the "php" one, let alone "no-debug-non-zts-20151012" or the php_imap.dll file, as you can imagine.

Sould I create the "*/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012*" directories and then, I don't really know how, download the php_imap.dll file and put it in the right directory?

I'm still relatively new to configuring PHP and making it all work so...could somebody please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you need `php_imap.dll` to be uncommented in `php.ini`? I don't need it with `brew install php56 --with-imap`.

Comment: The `--with-imap` option does no longer exist